Running this script in cmd exits immediately, and if I debugged it in Pycharm it always says exit code 0
I made this script for me to convert images to PDF in multiple folders for archiving. Yesterday it ran fine doing 245 folders to convert, but now today if I try to execute the script in cmd it always just returns to the prompt immediately.
import os
from PIL import Image

def convert_images_to_pdf(folder_path, output_pdf):
    image_files = [os.path.join(root, file) for root, _, files in os.walk(folder_path)
                   for file in files if file.lower().endswith(('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'))]
    
    if not image_files:
        print("No image files found in", folder_path)
        return

    try:
        first_image = Image.open(image_files[0])
        first_image.save(output_pdf, "PDF", resolution=100.0, save_all=True,
                         append_images=[Image.open(image_file) for image_file in image_files[1:]])
        print("PDF saved to", output_pdf)
    except MemoryError:
        print("Memory error occurred while processing folder:", folder_path)
        log_memory_error(folder_path, "E:/memory_error.log")

def load_processed_folders(log_file):
    return set(line.strip() for line in open(log_file, 'r') if os.path.isdir(line.strip()))

def save_processed_folder(log_file, folder_path):
    with open(log_file, 'a') as f:
        f.write(folder_path + '\n')

def log_memory_error(folder_path, log_file):
    with open(log_file, 'a') as f:
        f.write(folder_path + '\n')

# Example usage
root_folder = "E:/RESIDENTIAL"
output_folder = "E:/RESIDENTIAL_OUTPUT"
log_file = "E:/processed_folders.log"
memory_error_log_file = "E:/memory_error.log"

processed_folders = load_processed_folders(log_file)

for folder_name in os.listdir(root_folder):
    folder_path = os.path.join(root_folder, folder_name)
    if os.path.isdir(folder_path) and folder_path not in processed_folders:
        output_pdf = os.path.join(output_folder, folder_name + ".pdf")
        convert_images_to_pdf(folder_path, output_pdf)
        save_processed_folder(log_file, folder_path)

This should be what you see in the cmd and specified folder:

The output i got today:

P.S I put a box on the file names for privacy.

What do you mean when you say it "goes to the next line"? What exactly is the output now?

Please don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.

This is because you are not processing the folders that are already processed. Hence, there is nothing to do by the script. If you want to see same output, do following modification:
Replace
    if os.path.isdir(folder_path) and folder_path not in processed_folders:

With
    if os.path.isdir(folder_path):

